# Avoid inserting duplicate in array list

Tags: java

I have a method and I want avoid inserting duplicates in my arraylist which already has data in it. I am not sure if this is right:

```
 private static Kar karNameExist(Kar kar, ArrayList<Kar> karList) {
    if (karList.contains(kar.getInsertKar())){
        System.out.println(“Kar name exists”);
    }
return kar;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? It will be faster to try it than to ask here and wait for answers.

Comment: What does `kar.getInsertKar()` do?

Comment: If you don't want duplicates, can I suggest using a Set?

Answer (score 1):

You can [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) instead of ArrayList to avoid duplicate entry

Answer (score 0):

If you have `ArrayList<Kar>`, you want to say `karList.contains(kar)` to check if `kar` is already contained in the list. To make this work, you must implement proper `hashCode()` and `equals(Object)` in your Kar class (so ArrayList "knows" how to properly compare objects of type "Kar"

Comment: Can yoiu please help me on this for coding? I am novice to java.